# ListItemCollection - get text from value with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have `ListItemCollection`. Each element is of type `ListItem`. I want to return only text with item that has value given.

For now, I am using this function:

```
public string GetTextFromPaymentWayCollection(string value)
{
  ListItemCollection listPaymentWays = DB.GetList();

  foreach (ListItem item in listPaymentWays)
  {
    if (item.Value == value)
    {
      return item.Text;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Is there a way to do this with LINQ, instead of using this function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `listPaymentWays` is of [`ListItemCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) that does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`. The linq methods are extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>`.

For example the signature of [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ```
> public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(
>     this IEnumerable<TSource> source
> )
> ```

What you should do is first `Cast` (which will return an `IEnumerble<ListItem>`)  and then use the `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var result = listPaymentWays.Cast<ListItem>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == value)?.Text;
```

*The `?.` is C# 6.0 Null Proparation feature.*

*Also I'd recommend that `DB.GetList()` will expose a method that will get the value so the filtering will happen in the database and not in memory. It is a waste to bring all the data, create `ListItems` of it to then just take a single item.*

Comment: Thanks, this works. What is this question mark at the end? Perhaps you have link to documentation about that?

Answer (score 6):

You need to Cast it first to use `Where`. The rest is just ordinary Linq.

```
string s = listPaymentWays.Cast<ListItem>()
                          .ToDictionary(i => i.Value, i => i.Text)
                          .Where(x => x.Value == value)
                          .FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Comment: Why convert to dictionary and then do `Where`? no need :)

Answer (score 1):

```
return listPaymentWays.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == value)?.Text;
```

Should work fine.

Comment: Why I can't use FirstOrDefault on ListItemCollection?

Comment: @FrenkyB did you include System.Linq?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but you can use the already available (since .NET 1.1), non-LINQ method `FindByValue`:

```
return listPaymentWays.Items.FindByValue(value)?.Text;
```